# SQL Dynamic Column Name as a Counter

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, I want to write a dynamic SQL query that will update the row by checking different columns in the WHERE clause.

The columns in the WHERE clause has the format X1,X2,...,X10 - so i want to use @cnt as a counter concatenated to the column name X at each iteration.

I keep getting an error :

> The transaction log for database 'DBName' is
>   full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'

If I write the query 10 times it works fine, so it should be something with the loop or converting the int to char

This is my query so far - added all important parts:

```
 @y char(3) //SP Parameter

 DECLARE @table varchar(50)
 DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

 DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
 DECLARE @count VARCHAR(2)

 SET @table = CONCAT('X_',@y)

 WHILE @cnt <= 10     
   SET @count = CAST(@cnt as VARCHAR);
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ',@table,' SET X1 = CASE WHEN X1 <> '''' THEN X1 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X2 = CASE WHEN X1 = '''' or X2 <> '''' THEN X2 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X3 = CASE WHEN X2 = '''' or X3 <> '''' THEN X3 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X4 = CASE WHEN X3 = '''' or X4 <> '''' THEN X4 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X5 = CASE WHEN X4 = '''' or X5 <> '''' THEN X5 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X6 = CASE WHEN X5 = '''' or X6 <> '''' THEN X6 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X7 = CASE WHEN X6 = '''' or X7 <> '''' THEN X7 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X8 = CASE WHEN X7 = '''' or X8 <> '''' THEN X8 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X9 = CASE WHEN X8 = '''' or X9 <> '''' THEN X9 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
  X10 = CASE WHEN X9 = '''' or X10 <> '''' THEN X10 ELSE ''VALUE'' END
  WHERE X'+@count+' IN (SELECT P_CODE FROM P WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE ''%new%'' AND Y= ''',@y,''');
  EXEC (@sql);
  SET @cnt=@cnt+1;
 END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Smells like SQLServer

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @stickybit updated with the error i'm getting

Comment: You probably want to move `SET @count = CAST(@cnt as VARCHAR);` into the `BEGIN ... END;` block as otherwise your `WHILE` loop's body only consists of `SET @count = CAST(@cnt as VARCHAR);`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to correct syntax, no idea what is ultimate goal ?

```
declare @y char(3)='1'

DECLARE @table varchar(50)

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1

DECLARE @count VARCHAR(30)

SET @table = CONCAT('X_',@y)

WHILE (@cnt <= 10 )

BEGIN

SET @count = CAST(@cnt as VARCHAR(3));


set @sql=''


SET @sql = 'UPDATE '+@table+' SET X1 = CASE WHEN X1 <> '''' THEN X1 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X2 = CASE WHEN X1 = '''' or X2 <> '''' THEN X2 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X3 = CASE WHEN X2 = '''' or X3 <> '''' THEN X3 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X4 = CASE WHEN X3 = '''' or X4 <> '''' THEN X4 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X5 = CASE WHEN X4 = '''' or X5 <> '''' THEN X5 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X6 = CASE WHEN X5 = '''' or X6 <> '''' THEN X6 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X7 = CASE WHEN X6 = '''' or X7 <> '''' THEN X7 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X8 = CASE WHEN X7 = '''' or X8 <> '''' THEN X8 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X9 = CASE WHEN X8 = '''' or X9 <> '''' THEN X9 ELSE ''VALUE'' END,
X10 = CASE WHEN X9 = '''' or X10 <> '''' THEN X10 ELSE ''VALUE'' END
WHERE X'+@count+' IN (SELECT P_CODE FROM P WHERE [DESCRIPTION] LIKE ''%new%'' AND Y= '+@y+')';
--EXEC (@sql);

print @sql

SET @cnt=@cnt+1;

END
```

I) Avoid RBAR (like loop ,cursor)

ii) Use sp_executesql

Comment: Why did you comment out EXEC (@sql);

Comment: @MarwahAbdelaal, That is not big deal,you can uncomment it,it would not have run anyway in my machine.print is there to check valid syntax.